# Generate Items in DropDownList based on selection of item from another DropDownList

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005

I've two dropdownlists. One dropdownlist working as menu for second one.
suppose one dropdownlist is for Course-Category then based on selected category of course by user the second dropdownlist will show course names.
Also I'm storing items in collections of dropdownlist.
I'm using dotnet framework with c# and sql server 2005 database.

Comment: use cascaded dropdown list from ajaxcontrol toolkit, or just write a onselectedindexchange event handler for the first dropdown and populate the second one (also, make autopostback=true for the first dropdown) ...

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to do this would be to to write the code in the selection change event of the first drop down list. Based on the value the user selected, you can populate the second list by getting the items from the db.

If you are using WPF, then you could use databinding by binding the items collection of the second list to the selected item of the first drop down. This way you dont need to handle the selection changed event.

Edit: If you are using a web application, the process would be similar but you can handle the selection changed of the first drop down list in Javascript. In JQuery $.ajax or $.get can be used to get items pertaining to the selection from the server and this could be assigned to the second list. Of course, you would need a server side handler that can take in the selected item of the first list as an argument and return the corresponding values

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is with databindings. Create 2 fields in your class (one for categories(be it a List), and the second one - for courses(also a list)). Bind the first Dropdown with the Category list and the seciond dropdown with the Course list(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

it will be something like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=categoryList}}"
SelectionChanged="cmbBox_SelectionChanged" >
</ComboBox>
```

Implement the cmb_SelectionChanged method - with updating the course list by selected item from the Category list.

If you need more details - just ask.